# Does your partner have to also be behind the line when serving in pickleball?

Tags: rules, pickleball

This question is really just to confirm what I've read in the rules or really what is not specifically written in the rules...

USAPA rules state the following:

- 4.L. Service Foot Faults. During the serve, when the ball is
  struck, the server’s feet shall:

  - 4.L.1. Not touch the area outside the imaginary extension
    of the sideline.
  - 4.L.2. Not touch the area on the wrong side of the
    imaginary extension of the centerline.
  - 4.L.3. Not touch the court, including the baseline.

There are no rules specifically about the server's partner, but this has been a point of contention here and there in rec play.

[USAPA Rulebook](https://www.usapickleball.org/docs/ifp/USAPA-Rulebook.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule 4.B.7 seems to pretty clearly state that any player other than the server can stand wherever they wish (on their side of the net).

> 4.B.7. Partner Positions. In doubles, with the exception of the server (see 4.A.4) there is no restriction on the position of any player, as long as all players are on their respective team’s side of the net. They can be positioned on or off the court. The correct server must serve from the correct service court, and the correct receiver must receive the serve.